# EF Core 6 JSON column example

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-6.0

I have waiting  so long for Entity Framework JSON Support, Finally In their documentation of [EF Core 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/plan) , they have added JSON Column Support. But I can't find any example or documentation?

Lets say I have two classes

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateOnly JoiningDate { get; set; }


    public Address Address { get; set; }

}

public class Address
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

On class Employee, I need Address property Of type JSON, How to achieve that?

Comment: I read that as "***Plan** for Entity Framework Core 6.0*" - Which is kind of the same when I plan to do things on the weekend with my gf
.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, JSON column support is not implemented in EF Core 6.0. This is why you cannot find any documentation for it right now. It was planned to, but removed later nearly the release of EF Core 6.0. Now, it is planned for EF Core 7.0, and will be released in November 2022 with .NET 7, if everything goes according to the plan.

You can see the EF Core 7.0 plan here: [Plan for Entity Framework Core 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/plan#json-columns)

Also, you can track specifically the JSON column support in EF Core here: [Map JSON values stored in database to EF properties](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/4021)

Answer (score 1):

**EF 7.0 Upgrade**

Now you can have Json columns for sql server with EF 7:

```cs
public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; } //Save this object as Json
}

public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Author>().OwnsOne(
        author => author.Address, options =>
        {
            options.ToJson(); //will save the object as Json into database
        });
}
```